# Overloading of operators and issue with invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++

I made a class `Foo` for which I overloaded operators `< > <= >= != and =` now I have these 2 codes, both should do same, but only 1 works:

This works:

```
Foo foo = Foo("1");
if (foo <= something->foo) { ...
```

This doesn't work:

```
if (Foo("1") <= something->foo) { ...
```

The error in second version is:

> invalid operands to binary expression. Candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument.`

What does it mean and why it doesn't work?

Comment: How have you declared the operators? I'm guessing they take `Foo&` rather than `const Foo&`.

Comment: Yes, it's `bool operator <= (Foo &a, Foo &b);` I suppose that is a reason? Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote your operator in such a way that forbids passing in *rvalues*; an example might be, as pointed out by **@TartanLlama**, taking non-const reference.

```
bool operator<= (Foo& a, Foo& b); // will err
bool operator<= (const Foo& a, const Foo& b); // will work fine
```

The reason for that not working is that [it's simply disallowed in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object).